# History of the provisioned write capacity in DynamoDB beyond the last two weeks

Tags: dynamodb

Is there any way to see the history of the provisioned write capacity for a DynamoDB table beyond the last two weeks? When I go to the Amazon AWS console, select a DynamoDB table and look at the monitoring tab, the time range does not allow me to go beyond two weeks. Is there any other place to look at that could give me a longer history?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no  other place to look that could give a longer history of the provisioned write capacity for a DynamoDB table beyond the last two weeks. Therefore, one has to keep the records oneself if one wishes to have a longer history.